# MySQL - How can I know which field matches the result when using ORs

Tags: php, mysql, search, keyword

I'm creating an engine to find results in several fields using MySQL, something like:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.tid
WHERE 
(table1.field1 LIKE 'keyword%' OR table1.field2 LIKE 'keyword%')
AND
(table2.field1 LIKE 'keyword%' OR table2.field2 LIKE 'keyword%')
ORDER BY table1.id ASC;
```

But now I need to know which field matches the keyword... How can I do that?

BTW, I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unverified:

```
SELECT table1.*, 
       table2.*, 
       case (table2.field1 LIKE 'keyword%' and table1.field1 LIKE 'keyword%')
           when 1 
           then 'f1' 
           else 'f2' 
       end as field
FROM table1
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*, 'table1' as `target` as FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.tid
WHERE 
(table1.field1 LIKE 'keyword%' OR table1.field2 LIKE 'keyword%')
UNION ALL 
SELECT table1.*, table2.*,'table2' as target FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.tid
WHERE 
(table2.field1 LIKE 'keyword%' OR table2.field2 LIKE 'keyword%')
```

and then check if `target` is table1 or table2 when you retrieve the results

Answer (score 1):

You could add columns for your conditions

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*, 
table1.field1 LIKE 'keyword%' AS Table1Field1Match, 
table1.field2 LIKE 'keyword%' AS Table1Field2Match,
table2.field1 LIKE 'keyword%' AS Table2Field1Match, 
table2.field2 LIKE 'keyword%' AS Table2Field2Match
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.tid
WHERE 
(table1.field1 LIKE 'keyword%' OR table1.field2 LIKE 'keyword%')
AND
(table2.field1 LIKE 'keyword%' OR table2.field2 LIKE 'keyword%')
ORDER BY table1.id ASC;
```

Comment: Not sure if it would make a difference but having the LIKE in both the SELECT and the WHERE might make MySQL do the match twice. String matching can be expensive (especially with ORs) so might be better to do the matching in the SELECT and use HAVING to filter the results?

Comment: HAVING is generally never better. In some cases, it still needs to generate the full resultset before filtering it down, slowing everything to a crawl. In this case, since the conditions in the SELECT part will only be evaluated for matching rows, I don't think it's going to have a huge impact.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you can do this :

```
Table X
Field1      Field2
-------------------
boat        caca
hello       boat

$Keyword = 'boat';
while($Res = blabla){
    if(strpos($Res['Field1'], $Keyword) !== false){
        echo 'String found in Field 1<br />';
    }

    if(strpos($Res['Field2'], $Keyword) !== false){
        echo 'String found in Field 2<br />';
    }
}

// Will output
String found in Field 1<br />
String found in Field 2<br />
```

Comment: -1 Isn't this just making the processor do more work? You've already done the string matching in MySQL, why do it again in PHP?

Comment: Because it's easier first. Second, it take more processor round but, if MySQL has less job to do, your MySQL server is more faster, didn't you know this ? ...